# How to change Bluetooth broadcast device name?

Tags: bluetooth

I just can't figure a way to change my Bluetooth device name.

Is there any command?

Comment: Defect: [Cannot change bluetooth name](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/837196)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can't change bluetooth device name from control panel in ubuntu yet. Here is the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/837196), which provides this workaround:

> If you want to change the bluetooth device name permanently, you have
>   to create a file called [`/etc/machine-info`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-info.html) which should have the
>   following content:
>
> ```
> PRETTY_HOSTNAME=device-name
> ```

After this, restart the Bluetooth service:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Or reboot.

Comment: No need to restart. `service bluetooth restart` does the trick.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.10 you have to edit the value `Alias` in `/var/lib/bluetooth/*/settings` and call `sudo hciconfig hci0 name 'NewDeviceName@yourdomain.net'` - see my answer below: https://askubuntu.com/a/1326338/34298

Answer (score 89):

It seems the option was removed from the Bluetooth control panel, but you should still be able to change the name via the command line:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 name 'Device Name'
```

Once you run the command, you should be able to verify the change by bringing up the Bluetooth control panel again and checking the device name.

Comment: Useful Answer! Helped Me Thank You Very Much! :)

Comment: this is the safest and right way to do it, thx!

Comment: working ubuntu 13.10

Comment: It works, but the name is reset after reboot. I use Ubuntu 14.04. Can it be set permanently?

Comment: As @BornToCode points out, the change doesn't persist. Restarting the service with `service bluetooth restart` will show that the name change is reverted.

Comment: It certainly used to persist the name under `/var/lib/bluetooth/$addr/config`.  I wonder why it isn't doing so now?

Comment: @JamesHenstridge Perhaps investigating what *Blueman Bluetooth Manager* does will reveal how it now works?

Comment: In bluez-utils-5.50 there's no more the hciconfig util

Comment: This still works in Ubuntu 18.  Note that the settings gui does NOT reflect the change.  C api calls, do however.  Client devices will show the name change too, though they may take a few minutes to catch up (notably Windows takes it's time on this...)

Comment: This does not work **permanent** in Ubuntu 20.10, you also have to edit the value `Alias` in `/var/lib/bluetooth/*/settings`

Answer (score 22):

What I did (on 12.04):

1. device name is stored in `/var/lib/bluetooth/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/config`
2. delete it
3. restart (`~# service bluetooth restart`)
4. device name is rewritten in config (according to `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` ?)

Comment: If you don't like the bluetooth version of the device name, i.e. **hostname-0**, you can replace the line "**Name = %h – %d**" to simply "**Name = %h**" in step 4 above, which will get rid of the numbering suffix, as I just did in 13.04.

Comment: this works on 15.04

Answer (score 6):

I am using *Blueman Bluetooth Manager*. There is an option to change a computer's BT name in:

**Adapter → Parameters**

Comment: Thank you very much! This is more like the **Ubuntu-way** ( more user-friendly ;-) than other answers, and the latest version 1.23 has this feature via menu **Adapter → Preferences → Friendly Name**. Further info: https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman

Answer (score 6):

To change the bluetooth host name permanently, on Ubuntu 14.04 or later:

Open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>

1. Edit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf replacing "%h" with the computer name
   you want. "%h" always seems to represent "ubuntu" on my systems for some   reason.

   `gksudo gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf`

   For example change `Name = %h-%d` to `Name = gruber-%d`
   `
2. Remove /var/lib/bluetooth/*xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx*/config to make your system forget the old name. The *xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx* has a hexadecimal value unique to your bluetooth hardware.

   `sudo rm /var/lib/bluetooth/xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx/config`
3. Restart the bluetooth service

   `sudo service bluetooth restart`

   (Under 15.04 or later:)

   `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service`

You can check the new name by opening the Bluetooth settings. The last two steps are from Marx's answer.

Comment: This is my preferred answer, but rather than delete the `config` file I would rather edit it, as in _dreis nineoneone_'s answer. Incidentally, the `service` command still works in 15.04.

Answer (score 3):

The default Bluetooth package (`bluez`) comes with a command-line utility `bluetoothctl` that can set/reset the broadcast name (the "controller alias").

To change the broadcast name to `new-name`:

```bsh
bluetoothctl system-alias new-name
```

To remove the alias, setting the broadcast name back to your computer's name:

```bsh
bluetoothctl reset-alias
```

This will modify the appropriate settings in `/var/lib/bluetooth` automatically. MakeUseOf has a nice [introduction](https://www.makeuseof.com/manage-bluetooth-linux-with-bluetoothctl/) on what you can do with `bluetoothctl`.

Comment: Works like a charming

Answer (score 2):

You can change the name of a bluetooth remote device on your PC :

1. check the MAC adress of the device in the bluetooth settings. It looks:

   ```
   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   ```
2. open the Terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo gedit /var/lib/bluetooth/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/config/info
   ```
3. if it asks for the password, type it (you won't see it)
4. the gedit will open up with that file.
5. modify (only) the value corresponding to 'Name'

   ```
   Name=modified_name_as_you_like_it
   ```

The change will not be instantaneous !

6. Restart the service (or the PC), using the command:

   ```
   sudo service bluetooth restart
   ```

Comment: If your adapter has an alias, also edit /var/lib/bluetooth/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/settings, and change that.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in Ubuntu 18.04. When you restart the `bluetooth `service, the device isn renamed successfully but is not connected yet. When you connect, a new `info` file is written which overwrites your chances and the device name is therefore reset.

Comment: in Ubuntu 20.10 you have to edit the value `Alias` in `/var/lib/bluetooth/*/settings`

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04 you can do this from the settings.

```
Settings > About > Device Name
```

**Reboot** your computer for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y nano
sudo nano /var/lib/bluetooth/*/config
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Update the value for “name”. In my case, it was: Ubuntu-0

Comment: This answer provides the same solution as many others, but with much less detail.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.10 look at

```
sudo grep Alias /var/lib/bluetooth/*/settings
```

edit the value `Alias` with

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/bluetooth/*/settings
```

For example call it `NewDeviceName@yourdomain.net`

Then call

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 name 'NewDeviceName@yourdomain.net'`
```

No need for reboot or bluetooth restart.

Alternatively you can do this from the settings:

```
Settings -> Info -> Gerätename
```

I guess in english it is:

```
Settings -> About -> Device Name
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04, the following GUI option allows renaming in the *Bluetooth Manager*:

1. Bluetooth Manager
2. Right click on BT device
3. Rename device
4. Enter new
   name