# How to change bluetooth device name permanently?

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change bluetooth device name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80960/how-to-change-bluetooth-device-name)

Any ideas?

I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80960/how-to-change-bluetooth-device-name), but name is `ubuntu-0` again after reboot and after switching of bluetooth

Comment: Take a look at [the answer there](http://askubuntu.com/a/80963/46531) which links to the bug report. There is another solution at answer #6. Try this.