# How to change a bluetooth device's permanenty on all devices (headphones) name in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04, headphones

This is not a duplicate of [How to change Bluetooth broadcast device name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80960/how-to-change-bluetooth-broadcast-device-name)

I tried

`cd /var/lib/bluetooth`

`sudo vi F8:A2:D6:F8:E7:E8 config`

F8:A2:D6:F8:E7:E8 being my device bluetooth mac and there were a list of mac addresses
one of which was my headphones and changed the info file's name from JBL T460BT to friday june
and `sudo service bluetooth restart` for a brief amount of time when not connected the name remains [fridaySound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99q4b.png) when I reconnect it changes back to [JBL T460BT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE3zE.png)

Answer (score 0):

what you could do (worked for me in ubuntu 22.10)

```
sudo su -

vi /var/lib/bluetooth/"YOURPC'sMACADDRS"/F8\:A2\:D6\:F8\:E7\:E8/info
```

*remember to add a "\" before the ":" when typing the Mac Address

Add a line at the end of [General] with the alias, example:

```
Alias=BT-Music-Livingroom
```

Esc, wq, Enter to save and exit vi editor

then restart bluetooth with command:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```